# Cómo mandar una variable en Laravel al Blade solo si esta viene llena

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Necesito pasar una variable a Blade de Laravel solamente si esta viene llena (si viene vacía me va a tirar un error de non-object). La variable es la siguiente:

**Controller**

```
$respuestaModif = EncuestaRespuesta::where('encuesta_fk', $encuesta->id)
                    ->orderBy('fecha_registro', 'desc')
                    ->first();
```

La idea es que la variable $respuestaModif solamente se envíe cuando tenga datos, si viene vacío, simplemente no se va a mandar.

Comment: ¿cómo estás enviando la variable?

Comment: return View::make('encuesta.digitar')
                    ->with('respuestamodif', $respuestaModif);

Answer (score 2):

Lo que te conviene hacer es usar la directiva de blade `@isset`

Si la variable está en null no renderiza nada y sino...

```
@isset($respuestaModif)
    {{$respuestaModif->id}}
@endisset
```

Answer (score 1):

Una solución simple con una verificación si contiene algo la variable $respuestaModif:

```
$respuestaModif = EncuestaRespuesta::where('encuesta_fk', $encuesta->id)
                ->orderBy('fecha_registro', 'desc')
                ->first();

if (isset($respuestaModif)) {
    return View::make('encuesta.digitar')->with('respuestamodif', $respuestaModif);
} else {
    return View::make('encuesta.digitar');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pues en caso de tu pregunta

```
$respuestaModif = EncuestaRespuesta::where('encuesta_fk', $encuesta->id)
            ->orderBy('fecha_registro', 'desc')
            ->first();

if ($respuestaModif!=null) {//ó isset($respuestaModif) por no repetir la otra respuesta
    return View::make('encuesta.digitar',compact('respuestaModif');
} else {
    return View::make('encuesta.digitar');
}
```

Ya que `first`(que retorna el primer Modelo de una colección) retorna `null` si no existe **Modelo** alguno, en caso de que utilices `get`(que retorna una colección) en vez de `first` puedes utilizar funciones como `isEmpty()` o simplemente comparar con un `count($arreglo)==0` función que retorna la cantidad de elementos en una colección.

**Pero NO te aconsejo hacer esto en el controlador**, ya que de una forma u otra utilizas la variable `$respuestaModif`, lo que yo te recomendaría es hacer esta pregunta o este `if` en la vista.

**Ejemplo:**

```
<div class="navbar-custom-menu">
    solo es un html de ejemplo
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        @if(isset($respuestaModif))
            <li>$respuestaModif->algunaPropiedad</li>
        @else
            <li>El dato no existe</li>
        @endif
    </ul>
</div>
```

Y pues claro en tu controlador dejas de hacer el `if` y envias el dato tal cual

```
$respuestaModif = EncuestaRespuesta::where('encuesta_fk', $encuesta->id)
            ->orderBy('fecha_registro', 'desc')
            ->first();
return View::make('encuesta.digitar',compact('respuestaModif');
```

Answer (score 0):

Si realmente quiere comprobar que "$respuestaModif" no contenga un valor deseado, simplemente revisa que no sea nulo o mejor aun, que el objeto devuelto sea una instancia de la clase deseada.

```
if($respuestaModif instanceof EncuestaRespuesta){
// La encontro
}else{
//No la encontro
}
```